# JavaScript innerHTML = javascript function that returns string

Tags: javascript, html, function

How can I make it so that i can use the string that is returned in myFunction inside the .innerHTML?

```
myFunction(test) {
    return "Success";
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myFunction(test);
```

Comment: It depends element is of which type, it will work

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing the `function` keyword. `myFunction` is name of the function but you need to use `function` as key word before this name

```
function myFunction(){
        return "Success";
    }

document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = myFunction();
```

If it is an anonymous function definition
then

```
var myFunction=function() {
    return "Success";
}
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = myFunction();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8xxamcxw/)

Comment: sorry i meant to add that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should work if you actually declared it by using the `function` keyword. Also, be aware that not all elements have the `.innerHTML()` method.

With the `function` keyword, your function should look like this:

```
// Declaring the function
function myFunction() {
    return "Success";
}

// Calling the function
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = myFunction();
```

**I would, however, write it like this**:

```
// Declaring the function
function myFunction(test) {
    document.getElementById(test).innerHTML = "Success";
}

// Calling the function
myFunction("test");
```

Writing the function the second way will enable you to call the function for any element as you can pass its `id` as a parameter.

Remember: `innerHTML()` applies to every object that can contain HTML like `<div>`s, `<span>`s and other elements as well as `form controls`. That means that elements with `self-closing tags` will not accept it.